# When was David Tennant's Doctor in "Day of The Doctor"?

Tags: doctor-who, timeline, the-day-of-the-doctor

After re-watching the 50th anniversary special of Doctor Who I was wondering at what point in time David Tennant's doctor was along his own timeline. He mentions to the rabbit that he is 904 and he recognises Bad Wolf because of Rose.

So at when, according to his companions, does the Doctor get married to Queen Elizabeth 1 and meet his past and future selves, and then what time does he go back to in the TARDIS?

Comment: Definately after Martha started, for he didn't know what Queen Elizabeth had to do with him when they saw her in Martha's second episode. Hopefully my random nugget of information will help someone :D

Comment: At the beginning of the End of Time, he mentioned to the Ood that "The Virgin Queen was no longer...ahem..." and didn't finish the sentence.

Comment: It's all Wibbly-Wobbly Timey-Wimey...

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It's presumably at some point between the specials *The Waters of Mars* and *The End of Time*, because at the end of *The Waters of Mars* he's standing in a snowy street on Earth and suddenly sees a vision of Ood Sigma standing there, then at the beginning of *The End of Time* the TARDIS materializes on the Ood homeworld, and looking at [this transcript](http://www.chakoteya.net/DoctorWho/30-17.htm), here was the first bit of dialogue between them:

> DOCTOR: Ah! Now, sorry. There you are. So, where were we? I was
>   summoned, wasn't I? **An Ood in the snow, calling to me.** Well, I didn't
>   exactly come straight here. Had a bit of fun, you know. Travelled
>   about, did this and that. Got into trouble. You know me. It was
>   brilliant. I saw the Phosphorous Carousel of the Great Magellan
>   Gestadt, saved a planet from the Red Carnivorous Maw, named a galaxy
>   Alison. **Got married. That was a mistake. Good Queen Bess.** And let
>   me tell you, her nickname is no longer. Ahem. Anyway, what do you
>   want?
>
> SIGMA: You should not have delayed.
>
> DOCTOR: The last time I was here you said my song would be ending
>   soon, and I'm in no hurry for that.

"Good Queen Bess" was one nickname for Queen Elizabeth (see [this book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0688179614) for example), and "The Virgin Queen" was another, which is probably what the Doctor was jokingly referring to when he said "And let me tell you, her nickname is no longer. Ahem." So apparently the marriage to Queen Elizabeth was part of his "I didn't exactly come straight here" adventures, procrastinating on hearing what Ood Sigma had to tell him because last time the Doctor had met him in the flesh, in "Planet of the Ood", Ood Sigma had told him "I think your song must end soon." (likewise, in Planet of the Dead, the psychic Carmen had told him 'No, but you be careful. Because your song is ending, sir.')

Comment: Just adding this on for extra proof; in "Voyage of the Damned", the Doctor claims to be 903 years old, while in "The End of Time", he states that he is 906. In "The Day of the Doctor", he claims to be 904, so at the very least, it must absolutely be in between "Voyage of the Damned" and "The End of Time". To narrow that down even further, note that he has no companion with him in "The Day of the Doctor", which is in accordance with him travelling alone in the Series 4 specials.

Comment: @Amy -- Good point, and I see from the 10th Doctor section of [The Doctor's Age](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Doctor's_age) that there was also an audio adventure with Donna Noble that had him saying he was still 903. So, it seems like he spent several years procrastinating on responding to Ood Sigma's summons.

Answer (score 0):

I did some research of my own and rewatched "The Day of the Doctor". Now in 
"The Day of the Doctor" the 10th Doctor says that he's 9004 years old and in the end of time he says that he's 9006 so I did some thinking if you put
9004+2 you get 9006 that means the Doctor spent 2 years avoiding the ood
Summons.

Comment: 904 not 9004 years old.

Comment: But still 2 years have elapsed.

Answer (score 0):

Ten is bought there using a Time Fissure. And when he goes back to his TARDIS, the War Doctor says he won't remember this as he has been pulled out his timeline for the event, and Ten says he won't remember it either.

So it’s after Rose and Martha leave. He can't remember it, which is why Queen Elizabeth hates him and he doesn't know why.

Comment: I'm not sure this answers the question; when he leaves, what time does he return to?

Comment: For the record when the old queen hates the doctor - he doesn't know why because it had not happened for him yet.

Answer (score -2):

I think at the start of Martha's companionship, straight after Doomsday. Because he takes years alone sometimes, which he has mentioned. And he was traveling alone straight after Martha and it looked like The Doctor had just taken off in the TARDIS and was flicking switches when Donna appeared in there.